# Unknown missing space on C drive

Tags: windows-10, windirstat

I am running Win 10 Pro and have a Samsung SSD850EVO 500GB drive as my C drive. My used space normally shows 107GB however for some reason it now shows used space as 240GB. I have run Windirstat and a large (129.4Gb) unknown file shows up but Windirstat will not allow me to delete this. Folloewing on from other threads, please does anyone have an idea as to how I can delete this file. My system restore is set to 15GB

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the results of this WinDirStat output, which shows the unknown file?

Comment: OK how can I do that -sorry new to this support foirum

Comment: Where is the unknown file located? What is it named (just Unknown)? What happens when you try to delete it. Is there an error? Nothing happens?

Comment: On Windows, there will be a program called Snipping Tool. You should know how to open it. Make a screenshot by clicking `New` and dragging a box over the WinDirStat window. Once you let go of the mouse, another window will appear. Click the button with the two sheets of paper on it. It should copy the image. Now in the [Edit Menu](https://superuser.com/posts/1305833/edit), hold CTRL and press G. (Click on the text box first). Hold the CTRL and press P. Your image should now upload.

Comment: File shows on C drive and is just shown as <Unknown> and 129.4GB. When highlighted the command tools (File, Edit, Clean Up etc are greyed out and not available

Comment: If you try to delete it from cmd or powershell does it throw an error?

Comment: Sorry unable to upload an image of the Windirstat display results

Comment: Are you able to try to delete the file from cmd or powershell?

Comment: no - nothing showing in cmd or Poweershell

Comment: What do you mean nothing showing? In powershell when you type ***Remove-Item c:\Unknown*** there is not an error?

Comment: PS C:\Users\Richa> Remove-Item c:\Unknown
Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Unknown' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item c:\Unknown
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Unknown:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Comment: Apologies ran Powershell and got the above result

Comment: Does Get-ChildItem c:\*.* -force find the file?

Comment: Thank you for your replies - sorry that command returns nothing

Comment: I'm at a loss then. Does windows explorer show the file or just WinDirStat? Also how much free space does windows explorer show for that drive?

Comment: Nothing shows in Windows Explorer and free space shows 228GB.

Answer (score 0):

In my case... it was the system restore files that had accumulated everytime there was a windows update or new software installation. Got rid of it by deleting all the old system restore files(caution: it deleted all the restore files), then enabled again...as its a quick and useful type of backup one should have. In the process I got back about 90% of the 'unknown' disk space.